# Entity Framework Core - DefaultValue(true) attribute not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

What is the code-first approach to set the default value of a database column in entity framework core?

**Attempt #1:** Using the `DefaultValue` attribute on the model doesn't seem to work

```
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool ShowInReports { get; set; }
```

After running the migration, the following code is generated by dotnet ef version 5.0.1:

```
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
        name: "ShowInReports",
        table: "ParametersUsed",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: false);
```

Attempt #2: trying to define the value in `OnModelCreating` doesn't recognize the function:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<TableName>()
        .Property(t=> t.ShowInReports)
        .HasDefaultValue(true);
```

Error: `'PropertyBuilder<bool>' does not contain a definition for 'HasDefaultValue' and no accessible extension method 'HasDefaultValue' accepting a first argument of type 'PropertyBuilder<bool>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Have you added the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/) package?

Comment: Just figured out that for the Attempt #2, the Relational package is needed. Thanks @Riwen

Comment: Any idea how to get the DefaultValue attribute working, without using the HasDefaultValue in the OnModelCreating

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reposting my comment, since it seems to be the answer, too.

You need to add the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/) package for the `HasDefaultValue` extension method to be available.

As for the `DefaultValue` attribute, I'm not convinced it can be used with EF Core, or with EF in general. I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score -3):

public bool ShowInReports { get; set; } = true; Try this.

Comment: Tested, doesnt work...